# Web service returns partial data

Tags: c#, .net, xml, web-services, response

i am calling a web service hosted by my client.
when i call the method of that web service from my local environment i receive partial xml response. Eg:

```
<WEBRESPONSE date="2014-06-11T19:30:00">
  <ITEM1 some_attribute="value" some_date="2014-06-11T19:30:00">
    <DETAILS />
  </ITEM1>
  <ITEM2 some_attribute="value" some_date="2014-06-11T19:30:00">
    <DETAILS />
  </ITEM2>
</WEBRESPONSE>
```

Whereas, when i call the web service from the clients environment i receive proper xml response.

```
<WEBRESPONSE date="2014-06-11T19:30:00">
  <ITEM1 some_attribute="value" some_date="2014-06-11T14:22:00">
    <DETAILS some_detail_attribute1="1234567" some_detail_attribute2="abcdef" />
  </ITEM1>
  <ITEM2 some_attribute="value" some_date="2014-06-11T10:00:00">
    <DETAILS some_detail_attribute1="1234568" some_detail_attribute2="pqrstu" />
  </ITEM2>
</WEBRESPONSE>
```

The inner node 'DETAILS' is returned without any attributes. While the other nodes are returned with proper values.

Could this be a network issue? Or what...?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: All else being equal, it sounds like there's some IP address filtering going on within the service. This isn't really an SO issue - I'd suggest talking to the client's developers and getting them to look into it.

Comment: You are receiving a fully formed and complete (in terms of format) response.  This is a content or permissions issue, not a network issue.

Comment: Also - please don't take my close vote the wrong way, it's simply that this is an entirely non-reproducible issue.

Comment: I misinterpreted the different output to come from your code, not an external supplier. My mistake, I misread. @AdrianWragg's answer seems to be correct, the supplier is actively deciding to not share the same information with an external caller.

Comment: I did some more digging and found that i am receiving proper details for other request parameters. Eg: when requesting details for 'X' i get improper XML whereas when requesting for 'Y' i get valid XML response. While in clients environment i receive valid response for both 'X' and 'Y'.

Comment: @Adrian Wragg I don't think its a IP address filtering as i can see valid response for some other request parameter. I dont mind if you have given my question a close vote.

Comment: @Joe may be both the values 'X' and 'Y' have different permissions.

Comment: @Flater while requesting for both 'X' and 'Y' i am an external caller, still i get valid response for 'Y'

Comment: but anyways i have reported this to the client ...awaiting response from them..thank u all for your suggestions..

Comment: @Ankit: I meant "External" as "outside the client's environment", which is how you phrased it :)